# Image to ArrayBuffer in Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

You need to get a jpg and convert to arrayBuffer, does anyone have any idea how to do this? I tried doing using a function below but without success for a Microsoft API

```
 document.querySelector('#inputImage').addEventListener('change', function() {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {

      var arrayBuffer = this.result,
      array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);


    };
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this function to convert your base64 Image to an Array Buffer

```
export async function base64ToFile(dataURL, fileName) {
    const arr = dataURL.split(',');
    const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
    return (fetch(dataURL)
        .then(function (result) {
            return result.arrayBuffer();
        }));
}
```

Comment: `fetch` to get a Response from a base64 string! That's super smart! Thanks! I'm stealing your technique 

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelector('#inputImage').addEventListener('change', function() {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {

      var arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
        console.log(arrayBuffer);
      };
     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);  
 });
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inputImage">
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For [the modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_blob_arraybuffer) just use the [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method of the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object which is inherited from the [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object:

```js
const ab = await input.files[0].arrayBuffer();
```

```js
const input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "file";
document.body.append(input);
input.addEventListener("change", async event => {
    const ab = await input.files[0].arrayBuffer();
    const ui8a = new Uint8Array(ab);
    console.log("Uint8Array", ui8a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that `this` is something else in your code. Either use `bind()` :

```
reader.onload = function() { .... }.bind(this);
```

or use a fat arrow syntax:

```
reader.onload = () => { .... };
```

---

Because `this.result` if `result` is the property/attribute of input then i would say that this does not refers to the input element.

Comment: return error ReferenceError: arrayBuffer is not defined