# How to send formdata with react hook form next js route handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, multipartform-data, next.js13

The problem i have is just how to send formdata with react hook form to the api end point

I tried to append the data from react hook form to formdata but when i console.log, it returns undefined.I also tried the using the onchange method with out the {..field} input of react hook form it still same result

```
 const onSubmit = async (data: Inputs) => {
        console.log("data", data)


        const formData = new FormData();
        const port = formData.append("media", data.media); // Assuming 'media' is a property in 'data' and it's a file input
        const portt = formData.append("description", data.description);

        console.log(port)
        console.log(portt)


        try {
            setSubmitted(true);
            if (porfolio) {
                await fetch(`/api/portfolio/${porfolio.id}`, {
                    method: "PATCH",
                    body: formData,
                });
                setOpen(false);
                toast.success("Update Sucessful.");
            } else {
                const port = await fetch("/api/portfolio", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formData,
                });
                console.log("port", port)
                setOpen(false);
                toast.success("Created portfolio.Check /portfolio for changes.");
                form.reset();
                await port.json();
            }
            router.refresh();
        } catch (error) {
            setSubmitted(false);
            setError("error occured during the process. Report back to developer.");
        }
    };
```

```
//the input file field
  <FormField
                                            control={form.control}
                                            name="media"
                                            render={({ field }) => (
                                                <FormItem>
                                                    <FormControl>
                                                        <Input type="file" placeholder="media" {...field} />
                                                    </FormControl>
                                                    <FormMessage />
                                                </FormItem>
                                            )}
                                        />
```

```
/another example with route handler
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {

        const body = await request.formData();
        const file = body.get("media") as File;
        console.log("file:", file)
        const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
        const buffer = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
```

it gives the following error:  ⨯ TypeError: file.arrayBuffer is not a function

Comment: what have you got in file?

Comment: it for uploading images.so the file contains images to be uploaded

Comment: Check this link, it has a better solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817109/image-to-arraybuffer-in-js